# Use &lt; and &gt; instead of < and > in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am passing HTML content (with base64 image) into a web service. Our web service format won't allow '<' and '>', so I am using `&lt;` and `&gt;`. But I am not able to retrieve content. The HTML editor itself is not giving output.
How can I do this? Below is my sample code.

```html
<html><body>&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src="data:image/png;base64,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" /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;---------- Reply message ----------&lt;br /&gt;From: a.b@gmail.com&lt;br /&gt;Date: 02/01/2018 05:42:34 PM&lt;br /&gt;Subject: Re: Started-df&lt;br /&gt;To: d.e@gmail.com&lt;br /&gt;------------------------------&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class="gmail_extra"&gt;&lt;br clear="all" /&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div class="gmail_signature" data-smartmail="gmail_signature"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;&lt;span style="color: #999999;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div dir="ltr"&gt;&lt;span style="color: #999999; font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;Regards,&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;span style="color: #999999; font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;"&gt;&lt;span style="background-color: #ffffff;"&gt;a&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;span style="color: #999999; font-family: 'arial black',sans-serif; font-size: 12.8px;"&gt;Mobile: +913344556677&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;&lt;span style="color: #999999; font-family: 'arial black', sans-serif;"&gt;&lt;span style="background-color: #ffffff;"&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;div class="gmail_quote"&gt;On Tue, Jan 2, 2018 at 4:26 PM, &lt;a href="mailto:d.e@gmail.com"&gt;d.e@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt; &lt;span dir="ltr"&gt;&amp;lt;&lt;a href="mailto:d.e@gmail.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;d.e@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt;&amp;gt;&lt;/span&gt; wrote:&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;blockquote class="gmail_quote" style="margin: 0 0 0 .8ex; border-left: 1px #ccc solid; padding-left: 1ex;"&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;img /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;---------- Reply message ----------&lt;br /&gt;From: &lt;a href="mailto:d.e@gmail.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;d.e@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Date: 02/01/2018 03:42:06 PM&lt;br /&gt;Subject: Ticket Started-dfd&lt;br /&gt;To: &lt;a href="mailto:a.b@gmail.com.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;a.b@gmail.com.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Cc: &lt;a href="mailto:k.s@gmail.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;k.s@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt;;&lt;a href="mailto:t.m@gmail.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;t&lt;wbr /&gt;a@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt;;&lt;a href="mailto:d.e@gmail.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"&gt;dmeeu.&lt;wbr /&gt;entity@gmail.com&lt;/a&gt;;&lt;br /&gt;------------------------------&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;dfgd&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/blockquote&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</body></html>
```

Comment: What is the content type you're returning on your webservice?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..it's text/html type

Comment: What kind of web server are you using?

Comment: we r using IIS web server.

Comment: Could you maybe post the server code that is rendering this html code? I think the more code that is provided the better we'll be able to see what exactly is going on, and we'll be able to have more of a full picture of what's going on.

Comment: I am not able to post whole thing here..because it is very big content.What else I can do?

Comment: ```<html><body>``` seems to include the forbidden characters?

Comment: No,Request is firing properly but response is coming as base64 format instead of image..like <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA">